# WordPress ACF Save Post function, need it only to fire when the page saved is custom post type. Or, if field is present?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to manipulate the **my_acf_save_post** function to do some maths and update a field with the resulting number. This part is working, the fields **full_market_price** and **example_price** are used to work out **calculated_price**.

I did this some days ago but have now run in a problem whenever trying to save a page, or post that doesn't need this function, and doesn't contain the ACF fields. So every section of the website rather than just the 1 that requires this maths. It results in various errors and I can't save the pages properly.

How can I make this code snippet only work if the page being saved is within custom post type? So it won't break the other pages?

I'm trying something using 
`if (is_single() && is_post_type('nameofposttype'))`

however I can't seem to get it right, PHP not my strongest! Is a better way to ask if the fields does not exist, then do nothing?

Many thanks for any help or ideas,

```
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

// get values
$fmp = get_field('full_market_price');
$saPercent = get_field('example_price');

// do something
$examplePrice = ($fmp / 100) * $saPercent;
update_field('calculated_price', $examplePrice, $post_id);

}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into a similar issue. I would do something like:

```
function my_acf_save_post ($post_id) {

  // If not CPT, exit
  if (get_post_type($post_id) != 'nameofposttype') {
    return;
  }

  // Remainder of code
  ...

}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```